# Obtaining a facebook access token to use with facepy

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I am doing a project for school where I have to get all of my friend data, and the friend data of some of my friends, from facebook in order to make a graph of it. To do this I am planning on using facepy, but in order to do that I need an access token. My question is how do I obtain this access token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`facepy` doesn't natively include a way for the OAuth process

https://github.com/jgorset/facepy/issues/22

You will need to use your own method or external library for the user to be guided via a web application.

[image: Server Login]

For example using `web.py` and `facepy` to get `me/posts` with `read_stream` permission

```
import web
from facepy import GraphAPI
from urlparse import parse_qs

url = ('/', 'index')

app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID"
app_secret = "APP_SECRET"
post_login_url = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"

user_data = web.input(code=None)

if not user_data.code:
    dialog_url = ( "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +
                               "client_id=" + app_id +
                               "&redirect_uri=" + post_login_url +
                               "&scope=read_stream" )

    return "<script>top.location.href='" + dialog_url + "'</script>"
else:
    graph = GraphAPI()
    response = graph.get(
        path='oauth/access_token',
        client_id=app_id,
        client_secret=app_secret,
        redirect_uri=post_login_url,
        code=code
    )
    data = parse_qs(response)
    graph = GraphAPI(data['access_token'][0])
    graph.get('me/posts')
```

For more info see

<sub>* Facebook API - User Posts: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

* Publish a Facebook Photo in Python – The Basic Sauce: http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/publish-a-facebook-photo-in-python-the-basic-sauce/

* Facebook and Python – The Basic Sauce: http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/facebook-and-python-the-basic-sauce/</sub>

Comment: Any chance you could update this? I'm working on a project with the facebook API and have been really struggling. As far as I can tell, web.py no longer works with Python 3.x

Answer (score -2):

Basically, you just have to log in. 
If you go to the [graph API overview page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) It will ask you to log in with your own facebook account. After that all of the links on the page will have an access token with permission to see whatever you can see.